# How do I add a SuppressMessage for type GlobalSuppression?

Tags: c#, fxcop, stylecop, suppressmessage

In my `GlobalSuppression.cs` I often end up with long justifications.  I want those to span multiple lines, but don't want to gloabally suppress SA1118.  Ideally it would be something like this:

```
[module: SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Design",
    "CA1056:UriPropertiesShouldNotBeStrings",
    Justification = @"
        A really long multi-line
        justification for suppressing 
        this.")]

[module: SuppressMessage(
    "StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules",
    "SA1118:ParameterMustNotSpanMultipleLines",
    Justification = "Justifications can get long.",
    Scope = "type",
    Target = "GlobalSuppression")]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  If I take off the `Scope` and `Target` it does.

On a side note, the syntax for Target is really cryptic.  I would love to find a reference or some instructions on how to generate proper `Target` strings by hand (i don't use Visual Studio).

Comment: Did you ever find a resource for this: "I would love to find a reference or some instructions on how to generate proper Target strings by hand"?

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru, sadly, no.  We have started to aggregate many examples internally by simply searching Github for `GlobalSuppression.cs` and reading existing from big projects (like dotnet itself).  But this specific case still eludes me.